# How do you input NaN valiues in 1st row 1st column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data=['a',2,],['b',4,1],['c',6,],['d',4.4,]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age','number'])
df
    Name    Age     number
0   a   2.0     NaN
1   b   4.0     1.0
2   c   6.0     NaN
3   d   4.4     NaN
```

I wanted to replace "a" with NaN values (1st row 1st column)

This error shows up

```
data=[,2,],['b',4,1],['c',6,],['d',4.4,]
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried this instead

```
data=['',2,],['b',4,1],['c',6,],['d',4.4,]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age','number'])
df

    Name    Age     number
0       2.0     NaN
1   b   4.0     1.0
2   c   6.0     NaN
3   d   4.4     NaN
```

I then checked for missing values and obviously it is not picking up the empty values in , row1,column 1

```
na= [features for features in df.columns if df[features].isnull().sum()>0]
na

['number']
```

Any suggestions on how to navigate through this issue.
Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Pandas is built in `numpy`, so simply use `np.nan`:

```
import numpy as np

data=[np.nan,2,],['b',4,1],['c',6,],['d',4.4,]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age','number'])
print (df)
```

Ouput:

```
  Name  Age  number
0  NaN  2.0     NaN
1    b  4.0     1.0
2    c  6.0     NaN
3    d  4.4     NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```
float('nan')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `math` module on `NaN` value

```
import pandas as pd
import math
data=[math.nan,2,],['b',4,1],['c',6,],['d',4.4,]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age','number'])
df
```

output

```
   Name Age number

0   NaN 2.0 NaN

1   b   4.0 1.0

2   c   6.0 NaN

3   d   4.4 NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas docs recommend [.iat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) for getting / setting individual values on dataframes. Indexed by row / column pair starting from 0.

So in your case, to set column 'Name' / row 0 to numpy's nan type (imported as np below) this would be:

```
df.iat[0,0] = np.nan
```